# Streaming video file from client to server

Tags: .net, silverlight, wcf, video, streaming

What would be the best way to stream a video from a client to a server using the .net framework? Something like, the client streams to a wcf service and the server can broadcast the stream to other clients connected. If the video file is converted into a stream and sent to the server how would the client consume the stream and display the video?

In other words, is it possible to stream a video using a Stream object and sending it to a wcf service which can then be consumed by other clients calling the service?

I've searched around google but everything seems outdated.

Thanks for the help,
Ryan

Comment: Have you tried to use  StreamedRequest and Stream transfer mode?http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731913.aspx

Comment: Hi Jack, thanks for the reply. I looked into making my wcf stream content to the server but I can't 'publish' the video out to clients until the stream is completed. I was maybe looking into encoding the video into a smooth streaming format using the expression encoder api but that would require a lot of resources from the client side and might not be the right solution.